# Command "make:seeder" is not defined in Lumen 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan, lumen-5.2

I'm developing my first Lumen project and I try to create a `seed class` for my database.

I'm trying to run the next command:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

But I always get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>
> Command "make:seeder" is not defined.
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
>   db:seed
>
>   make:migration
> ```

I'm searching a lot how to solve that problem but I did'nt find anything. Any ideas what I need to do?

I'm using `lumen-framework 5.2.*`

Comment: It's not available in Lumen. Many of the artisan helpers like that are not in Lumen.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use the seeder (I don't think). You just don't have a generator, need to create the class yourself. Like [this guy](http://loige.co/developing-a-web-application-with-lumen-and-mysql/#seedthedatabase) did.

Comment: @jszobody ok I'm guessing I'm going to start doing manually the seeding classes, Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`make:seeder` command is not available in Lumen.

To see all built-in commands, use the `php artisan` command in Lumen.

So, you will need to write the codes by yourself. What you can do is copy the skeleton file from Laravel and use it as a starter in your Lumen project.

Comment: Here is the gist that I have created for this sole purpose. https://gist.github.com/samundra/901cd62fa98f0673b1cbbeec2ec17c3b you can add it to `App/Providers/MakeSeedServiceProvider.php` and load it as `$app->register(App\Providers\MakeSeedServiceProvider::class);`. Now you'll have 'make:seeder'